# How to remove empty space between 2 <ul>'s

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create css tabs.Initially i tried coding at jsfiddle and it is working fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/McZV9/1/

http://img.ctrlv.in.s3.amazonaws.com/img/5198a15694cbb.jpg

When i copy paste the same thing in my [blog](http://www.ilovetrolls.org/p/test-page.html)

I get an empty space between the tabs and content.
http://img.ctrlv.in.s3.amazonaws.com/img/5198a1ba0ba44.jpg

i assumed there might be some similar css causing the empty space.But there was no css which have could have casued that empty space.Ignoring that,I added `!important` eveywhere.But still there's an empty space.Google chromes inspect element is also not giving any hints.can anyone help me please

Here is the basic code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>




                            <ul class="tabs clearfix">
                                <li><a href="#html" class="active">HTML</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#css">CSS</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="tabs-content">
                                <li class="active" id="html">
                                    grtgrtgrtg
                                </li>
                                <li id="javascript">
                                    erfefr

                                </li>
                                <li id="css">
                                    <p>Similar to the  the CSS is used to style the tooltip, or info box.</p>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

CSS

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .row:before, .row:after {
    content:'\0020';
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
    height:0
}
.row:after, .clearfix:after {
    clear:both
}
.row, .clearfix {
    zoom:1
}



.tabs {
    display:block;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #ddd;
    zoom:1;
    margin:24px 0 0 0;
    padding:0
}
.tabs li {
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-indent:0;
    list-style:none
}
.tabs li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:auto;
    height:29px;
    line-height:30px;
    border:solid 1px #ddd;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    font-size:13px;
    -webkit-transition:color 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:color 1s ease;
    -o-transition:color 1s ease;
    transition:color 1s ease;
    border-width:1px 1px 0 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 20px
}
.tabs li a:hover {
    background:#f0f0f0;
    color:#111;
    -webkit-transition:color .3s ease;
    -moz-transition:color .3s ease;
    -o-transition:color .3s ease;
    transition:color .3s ease
}
.tabs li a.active {
    background:#f8f8f8;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    top:-4px;
    padding-top:4px;
    border-left-width:1px;
    color:#111;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
    margin:0 0 0 -1px
}
.tabs li:first-child a {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-width:1px 1px 0
}
.tabs li:last-child a {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:3px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:3px;
    border-top-right-radius:3px
}
.tabs-content {
    background:#f8f8f8;
    color:#4c4c4c;
    display:block;
    border:solid 1px #ddd;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
    border-width:0 1px 1px;
    margin:0 0 24px -1px;
    padding:20px 30px 10px 30px
}
.tabs-content li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-indent:0;
    list-style:none
}
```

Comment: Right, we will help you, because you just shared a screenshot and screenshots are great... for a coding site! Share codes people, codes...

Comment: he posted the complete code on jsfiddle..

Comment: No,its my mistake,links to jsfiddle must be accompanied with codes as per rules.

Comment: @Domi His code on jsFiddle is working fine according to him. Nothing to look at there. The problem lies in that code being placed in a different context, which could be overridden by that context's CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not the space between the two `ul`. It's the height of your `.tabs li a`

Set these to:

```
.tabs li a { height: 30px; }
.tabs li a.active { height: 34px; }
```

tested that on your website and it looked like this:

[image]

Comment: i have tried this earlier.Re-applied.Still space is coming.Thanks anyways.

Comment: maybe because you are overriding that style? Take a look at the screenshot I added

Comment: oh ,it worked...will give u the answer when the system allows me too after 4 minutes..by the way......then how did the original code work on jsfiddle??i am amazed.

Comment: Because there are other values applied to your `a` on your live site inherited from the body and the rest of the document like `line-height` ... etc. Check `inherited styles` on Chrome dev tools. Thanks

Comment: it's those other classes that you didn't add. I will update the answer with what I meant

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30205/discussion-between-ahmad-alfy-and-michel)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the class `tabs-content` the space is coming.I see it in firebug